# Is it possible to create image download link when image comes from api data?

Tags: php, html

I'm working with API and I retrieve all data along with image by sending API request. Now i want to create image download link. In that case if image location is like `https://images.unsplash.com/photos/291762/unsplash-photo-291762.jpeg` 
So, How can i create image download link.
I also try using html Download attribute but it doesn't work it directly opens full images in tab.

Comment: Zip the image ,the give the link to the zip file

Comment: Try download attribute like this `download="unsplash.jpeg"`.

Answer (score 0):

Weird... I use Chromium-based Edge, and the plain `download` attribute works properly. The same goes for Firefox (mobile and desktop).

```
<a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photos/291762/unsplash-photo-291762.jpeg" download>
    Some content/image here
</a>
```

Or, you can take a look at [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery). It will require opening in a new tab on click though.

Comment: This method is doesn't work. It open image in browser tab

Comment: What browser did you use?

Answer (score 0):

This simple soultion will work. Add `?force=true` at the end of each url href attribute:

```
<a href="https://images.unsplash.com/unsplash-photo-291762.jpeg?force=true">Download</a>
```